# Sensitive data in input hidden field

Tags: javascript, html, security

We have to send **sensitive data** from our web application to the server.

This data is not written by the user who is working with the application, but is read from the DB and loaded into a **hidden input**.

Despite the fact that we use **HTTPS** protocol, that the sending is done via **POST**, and that the application would only be used by **logged in** users, someone from the team has shown his concern because if the user hits to '**View source code**' in the browser, he can see that sensitive data.

Don't know if `<input type="password" hidden ...>` would help.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Sensitive data should always be handled by the backend. You might want to pass an encrypted value or even a hash that sent back to the backend will decrypt or match the value. Backend sessions are also useful for that purpose

Comment: The problem is that the sensitive data is transmitted to the backend of another company

Comment: If the concern is to hide that data from the user, the transmission must be done by a backend api that does exactly the same as the frontEnd one but adding on the API call the value you don't want to show, your backEnd would be used as a proxy for the server, that proxy injecting the value you don't want on display

Comment: ok ok I see. Thanks